# Find the possible value of $x$ for $ \Bigg\vert \frac{3|x|-2}{|x|-1} \Bigg\vert \ge2 \ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the possible value of $x$ for

$$ \left\vert \frac{3|x|-2}{|x|-1} \right\vert \ge 2.$$

Comment: Putt this code to [wolframalfa.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com) `Reduce[Abs[(3*Abs[x] - 2)/(Abs[x] - 1)] >= 2, x, Reals]` if you want a quick solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $y = |x|$ and cross-multiply to get 
$$|3y-2| \ge 2|y-1|$$
This is equivalent to $$9y^2-12y+4 = |3y-2|^2 \ge 4|y-1|^2 = 4y^2-8y+4$$

or $y(5y-4) \ge 0$. Therefore $y \in \langle -\infty, 0] \cup \left[\frac45, +\infty\right\rangle$.

Hence $|x| \ge \frac45$ or $|x| = 0$ and by inspection in the original equation we also get $|x| \ne 1$.

We conclude $x \in \Big(\left\langle -\infty, -\frac45\right] \cup \{0\} \cup\left[ \frac45, -\infty\right\rangle \Big)\setminus \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: $x=0$ should also be a solution.

Comment: @Ernie060 Thanks, added.

Answer (score 1):

We have $|x|\neq 1$ and 
\begin{align}
\Bigg\vert \frac{3|x|-2}{|x|-1} \Bigg\vert \ge2 
\implies &
\left( \frac{3|x|-2}{|x|-1} \right)^2 \ge 4 
\\
\implies&
\frac{9 |x|^2-12|x|+4}{|x|^2-2|x|+1}\geq 4
\\
\implies & 
9 |x|^2-12|x|+4 \geq 4(|x|^2-2|x|+1)
\\
\implies & 
5 |x|^2-4|x| \geq 0 
\\
\implies & 
|x|(5 |x|-4) \geq 0 \quad \mbox{ or }  \quad x=0
\\
\implies & 
5 |x|-4 \geq 0 \quad \mbox{ or }  \quad x=0
\\
\implies & 
 |x| \geq 4/5 \quad \mbox{ or }  \quad x=0
\end{align}
The implications to the contrary also apply. Check for yourself.

Comment: In the third last step you should add "or $x=0$".

Comment: @Ernie060 Thanks for pointing out the error. I made the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as $\bigl|3+\frac{1}{|x|-1}\bigr| \geq 2$. We look at different cases:

**Case 1:** $3+\frac{1}{|x|-1}\geq 2$ or $\frac{1}{|x|-1}\geq -1$.

*Case 1a:* If $|x|>1$, the inequality is then trivially ok (positive number > negative number).

*Case 2a:* If $|x|<1$, we get $|x|-1\leq -1$, hence $x=0$.

**Case 2:** $3+\frac{1}{|x|-1}\leq -2$ or $\frac{1}{|x|-1}\leq -5$.

*Case 1a:* If $|x|>1$, there are no solutions.

*Case 2a:* If $|x|<1$, we get $|x|\geq \frac{4}{5}$.

Putting everything together and looking at the original inequality gives the solutions $x\in (-\infty, \frac{-4}{5}] \cup \{0\} \cup [\frac{4}{5},\infty) \setminus \{-1,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Either $ \frac{3|x|-2}{|x|-1}\ge 2$ or $ \frac{3|x|-2}{|x|-1}\le -2$.
Former gives $ \frac{|x|}{|x|-1}\ge 0$ and latter gives $ \frac{5|x|-4}{|x|-1}\le 0 $

Former gives x ranging from (-infinity,-1) U (1,infinity)

Latter gives x ranging from (-1,-$ \frac{4}{5}\ $),($ \frac{4}{5}\ $,1)

Taking union of both ranges: x belongs to (-infinity,-1) U (-1,-$ \frac{4}{5}\ $) U ($ \frac{4}{5}\ $,1) U (1,infinity) U {0}

Comment: Apologies for bad formatting...

Comment: In which step did you find the solution $x=0$?

Comment: former one: |x|/(|x|-1) >=0

Comment: it is 0 for x= 0